# Nginx 502 Bad getaway and can't change port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, httprequest

I'm trying to initiate requests from my React frontend through Nginx to my node js backend. I've tried almost 20 different Nginx configuration but I'm still getting 502 Bad getaway.

**My frontend code:**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        response: '',
        post: '',
        responseToPost: '',
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
            .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/hello');
        const body = await response.json();
        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
        return body;
    };
    handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch('/api/world', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
        });
        const body = await response.text();
        this.setState({ responseToPost: body });

    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <p>
                        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload. 
                    </p>
                    <a
                        className="App-link"
                        href="https://reactjs.org"
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    >
                        Learn React
                    </a>
                </header>
                <p>{this.state.response}</p>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Post to Server:</strong>
                    </p>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.post}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ post: e.target.value })}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <p>{this.state.responseToPost}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**My backend code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
// API calls
app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
});
app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  res.send(
      `I received your POST request. This is what you sent me: ${req.body.post}`,
  );
});
  // Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/home/matan/frontend/build')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/home/matan/frontend/build', 'index.html'));
  });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**Nginx configuration:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name moneyserver;
        location / {
            # This would be the directory where your React app's static files a$
            root /home/matan/frontend/build;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            error_page  405     =200 $uri;
        }

        location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

**Netstat info**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6673/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      730/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3202/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6673/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3202/sshd
```

Iv'e tried to change Nginx default 80 port to 5000 but it keeps sending to port 80

**edit**:

**I managed to change the port to 5000 but still get 502 bad getaway**

I think I read almost every possible tutorial but still I can't get response from those http request. when I'm trying to send the request without /api I'm getting html response I think it the frontend code and can't get the desired response.

Thanks!

Comment: Your netstat shows nothing listening on port 5000. Are you sure your nodejs server is running? Can you connect to it on `http://127.0.0.1:5000` without going through nginx?

Comment: I'm running my server with pm2. When I try to navigate to http://185.28.153.109:5000 I get nothing, as it does not exist...

Comment: I managed to change the port to 5000 but still get 502 bad getaway

Comment: try hitting curl call in cli to http://localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

Try to proxy pass `http://localhost:5000/api` also instead of keeping static build on both nginx and node js, try keeping build only on nginx.

Comment: Can you explain how to "  instead of keeping static build on both nginx and node js, try keeping build only on nginx "?

Comment: Since you have already mentioned the location of build folder in nginx.conf file, you can comment the static file code in node js.

Comment: You can comment these lines in nodejs and try running the servers again.

// Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/home/matan/frontend/build')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/home/matan/frontend/build', 'index.html'));
  });

Comment: Thanks, but I still getting 502 bad getaway when sending http://185.28.153.109:5000/api/world

Comment: It is showing same page on http://185.28.153.109/ and http://185.28.153.109:5000 as well which means it is fetching static build from both the servers, seems that the server is not running your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Change proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api;
then restart the nginx

Comment: changed to                                                                                                            `location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } `
                                                                                                                                  but still getting 502 bad getaway